# use callout instead of TextArea using flex 4 and action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

actually I have developed simple chat application for android device using Flex 4 and Cirrus. now I need some help regards of the Design. actually for the incoming Text Message I just used the spark TextArea. but I need to use "Callout" box like this [image: callOut]
kindly any one suggest me some idea regarding this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the TextArea for incoming text. A simple Label or StyleableTextfield would be much faster.
Considering your Callout, I don't see any reason to use one. Use a Skin that draws the box and arrow instead. That would be much lighter (hence faster) than using a Callout for every single message.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. can you tell me , how to create skin that draws box with arrow.. I can't get it clearly. kindly help me .

Comment: My approach would be to create a custom component that wraps either one of the mentioned TextField components with a SkinnableContainer/Component and skin that container. You could start taking a look into how the Callout is skinned and mimic the its skin.